# PayPal - recurring transaction not submitting address via IPN but non-recurring does

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

When using PayPal's payments standard offering, how can it be configured so that when the user is taken to PayPal's site and selects recurring (see screenshot below), the billing address is submitted to the IPN post-back page (and also captured in the IPN history for the transaction)?

Non-recurring payments do currently capture the billing address as expected.

We've tried including and excluding address_override to see if that would make a difference, but it didn't (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#id08A6F0T0JQN).

[image: Recurring Payment Selection on PayPal Form]

Answer (score 0):

To get the billing information, you have to contact PayPal and ask them to submit a ticket to enable receiving the billing information.  By default you just get shipping information but not billing to help protect PayPal users.

In this case shipping information was actually what was coming through for the non-recurring payments even though it labeled generically.

UPDATE: apparently this is actually only supported for non-recurring transactions.